# performance with jsflot, html5 canvas and setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, flot

I am developing a webpage which has 9 jQuery Flot graphs which are updated with

```
setInterval(function(){
    updateGraph1to8(data1);
}, 10);

setInterval(function(){
    updateGraph9(data2);
}, 10);
```

and three HTML5 canvas which instead is updated on an event.
Two of them are based on `data1` so they are drawn inside the event function that supply `data1` like:

```
onData1available(){
    //do math and stuff
    updateCanvas1();
    updateCanvas2();
}
```

while the remaining is based on `data2` and is drawn in the same way.

JS Flot graphs are drawn constantly as soon as the document is ready, they have no lag at all.
By the time I activate the canvas (the drawing is activated when a button is pressed), I notice a clear lag in the Flot graphs but none in the canvas.
I tried to move the Flot graphs drawing in the event function but everything was lagging as hell.
Then I tried to bring the canvases in a timer but it didn't really change anything.
My questions are:

1. Am I really reaching a performance bottleneck? (to me it's impossible)
2. What should be the best implementation to follow?
3. How do I enhance my code in order to avoid lag?
4. I thought asynchronous coding was a good way to avoid this thing, then why the timers aren't doing their job? Is it because they are all scheduled at 10ms? Is a sequential delay improving the situation?

SOLUTION:

http://jsfiddle.net/wMkJg/

Comment: Not much code to go by, in fact not enough to solve the problem. You have 2 intervals at 10ms that's 100 * 8 + 100 charts a second. Looking at the jsFlot web site and they  look like they have presentation over performance in mind. First thing is why are the charts being updated faster than the display refresh rate of ~16ms (you have approx 40 rendered updates per second on 9 charts for a total of 360 never displayed chart renders ). Yes you are reaching a bottleneck as you are way over cranking the device.

Comment: i set 10ms because at 50ms they were stuttering, at 10 ms the flow is nice and smooth. i'll try at 16ms, you can still feel the lag even if the timer are at 100ms.

Comment: The lag to me would be expected. But I have no information to judge the performance. You should not be using interval timers anyways, you should use `requestAnimationFrame`, it will pick the best possible frame rate the browser can manage for the task you give it. It will also sync to the display refresh, and let the browser know you are animating so you do not clash with the page rendering. Looking at jsflot it is not built to do what you are trying to make it do (guessing by the fact you want 9 realtime plots)

Comment: @Blindman67 tomorrow i will post some news about the requestAnimationFrame, could you suggest a good library for realtime plot? is this [link](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/) a good solution? flot seems good to me [link](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/)

Comment: @Blindman67 Ok, i've been able to use the "famous" polyfill to allow requestAnimationFrame. My last doubt is: is it true that the maximum fps reachable in the browser are 60? I ask this because if i increment the fps above 60, the drawing is even smoother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Solved using window.requestAnimationFrame trick